# How to plot the path and the movement of a robot?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rospy, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using turtlebot in gazebo and rviz. The robot moves from A to B, and I am wondering if there is an easy way (without the need to use matlab) to plot

1. the path that robot finds (e.g. based on the situation the robot can choose different path)
2. the movement of the robot from it's current position to the goal (how robot moves to reach its goal)
3. the robot's distance to obstacles around

link:[Image](http://learn-robotics.com/images/portfolio-10.jpg)

Using rqt_plot can solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258157/how-to-plot-the-path-and-the-movement-of-a-robot?/) by [Turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/29840/turtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_plot will plot this information if you publish it in a topic. Let's see in more detail what you want to do, first:

1. the path that robot finds: This is best displayed in RViz IMHO, because it will be super-posed to the map.
2. You need a XY plot, rather than the time-series visualization provided by rqt_plot
3. you need to publish this information if you want a graphic tool to be able to visualize it.

I suggest you to take a look at

https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler

https://vimeo.com/214389001

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1